# Weird Typescript string enum not resolving from a string

Tags: string, typescript, enums, type-conversion

I had an enumeration in my project defined like so

```
export enum RootPage {
  HOME = <any>'HomePage',
  LOGIN = <any>'LoginPage',
  TEST01 = <any>'Test01Page',
  LAUNCHPAD = <any>'LaunchpadPage',
  JOBS = <any>'JobsPage',
  MACHINES =<any>'MachinesPage',
  GVARS =<any>'GvarsPage',
  RESOURCES=<any>'ResourcesPage',
  CONFIGURATION=<any>'ConfigurationPage', 
  TABS=<any>'TabsPage'
};
```

Now in theory I should have been able to do:

```
constructor(
   private menuitemsService:MenuitemsService
) {}
let pageString = 'HomePage';
let rp:RootPage = RootPage[pageString];
let pi:PageInterface = this.menuitemsService.getPagebyRoot(rp)
```

MenuItemsService:

```
getPagebyRoot(rootPage:RootPage): PageInterface {
  ...
}
```

The only problem is, inside 'MenuItemService.getPagebyRoot() it would interpret, rp as HOME, rather than HomePage.

So I ended up having to create a utlility method in MenuItemService with a honking great switch statement.

```
 getRootPageFromString(name:string):RootPage {
    switch (name) {
        case RootPage.HOME.toString():
            return RootPage.HOME;
        case RootPage.LOGIN.toString():
            return RootPage.LOGIN;
        case RootPage.TEST01.toString():
            return RootPage.TEST01;
        case RootPage.LAUNCHPAD.toString():
            return RootPage.LAUNCHPAD;
        case RootPage.JOBS.toString():
            return RootPage.JOBS;
        case RootPage.MACHINES.toString():
            return RootPage.MACHINES;
        case RootPage.GVARS.toString():
            return RootPage.GVARS;
        case RootPage.RESOURCES.toString():
            return RootPage.RESOURCES;
        case RootPage.CONFIGURATION.toString():
            return RootPage.CONFIGURATION;
        case RootPage.TABS.toString():
            return RootPage.TABS;
    }
```

then substitute this line in my code:

```
let rp:RootPage = this.menuItemService.getRootPageFromString(pageString);
```

**There has to be a simpler approach.**

But it baffles me that I had to resort to this.

**Has anyone else had similar experiences?**

**Or found a simpler solution?**

**Update:**

Posted my own answer to the issue. Was because I was using Typescript **2.3.4** instead of **2.4+**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it was specific to version of Typescript I was using.

Version 2.3.4 has the issue. 2.4_+ seems to be ok. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191472/typescripts-string-enums-type-is-not-assignable-to-type).

I'd end up with message:

*Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'RootPage'*, if I used the following code:

```
let pageString = 'HomePage'; 
let rp:RootPage = RootPage[RootPage[pageString]];
```

Answer (score 4):

When you create enums in typescript (Under the hood) you get an object that looks like this:

**TypeScript:**

```
enum RootPage {
  HOME = <any>'HomePage',
  LOGIN = <any>'LoginPage'
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
RootPage = {
  "HOME": "HomePage",
  "LOGIN": "LoginPage",
  "LoginPage": "LOGIN",
  "HomePage: "HOME"
}
```

So when you access a property from this enum/object you get the value/key:

```
Console.log(RootPage["HOME"]);     // HomePage
Console.log(RootPage["HomePage"]); // HOME
```

This all comes to a simple conclusion: If you have the key, you can get the value, if you have the value you can get the key. **No need to do a long `case` for that**. It seems that you already have the value in hand.

Comment: You are correct:I thought I'd tried double RootPage[RootPage[string]. But obviously I couldn't have. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20RootPage%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20HOME%20%3D%20%3Cany%3E'HomePage'%2C%0D%0A%20%20LOGIN%20%3D%20%3Cany%3E'LoginPage'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20rps%3A%20string%20%3D%20'HomePage'%3B%0D%0Alet%20rp%3A%20RootPage%20%3D%20RootPage%5Brps%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20rp2%3A%20RootPage%20%3D%20RootPage%5Brp%5D%3B%0D%0Aalert(rp)%3B%0D%0Aalert(rp2)%3B%0D%0A