# String Enum in typescript error

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, enums

I tried to add a string enum to my Angular 2 project, but error occur during starting of project with npm:

```
ERROR in e:/projects/dbtool-fullstack/dbtool-client/src/app/shared/models/full-m
odels/enums/Sex.ts (2,10): Type '"Male"' is not assignable to type 'Sex'.
ERROR in e:/projects/dbtool-fullstack/dbtool-client/src/app/shared/models/full-m
odels/enums/Sex.ts (3,12): Type '"Female"' is not assignable to type 'Sex'.
ERROR in e:/projects/dbtool-fullstack/dbtool-client/src/app/shared/models/full-m
odels/enums/Sex.ts (4,8): Type '"NA"' is not assignable to type 'Sex'.
```

The Enum declaration:

```
export enum Sex {
  Male = 'Male',
  Female = 'Female',
  NA = 'NA'
}
```

And typescript version:

```
e:\projects\dbtool-fullstack\dbtool-client>tsc --version
Version 2.5.3

e:\projects\dbtool-fullstack\dbtool-client>npm list -g --depth=0
C:\Users\pavlo\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @angular/cli@1.4.4
+-- npm@5.5.1
`-- typescript@2.5.3
```

This type of Enum declaration should work starting from version 2.4.0

What could cause this?

**UPDATE**

When i use ng -v:

```
e:\projects\TESTENUMS>ng -v
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.4.9
node: 6.11.3
os: win32 ia32
@angular/animations: 4.4.6
@angular/common: 4.4.6
@angular/compiler: 4.4.6
@angular/core: 4.4.6
@angular/forms: 4.4.6
@angular/http: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.6
@angular/router: 4.4.6
@angular/cli: 1.4.9
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.6
@angular/language-service: 4.4.6
typescript: 2.3.4
```

the version of TS is 2.3.4 in this case. I don't know where does it come from though.

Comment: check if you are facing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191472/typescripts-string-enums-type-is-not-assignable-to-type

Comment: Just tried this and it works ok, you are probably using another version of `tsc` that the one you work with in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IMPORTANT**

It turned out that current version of Angular (4.4.6) doesn't support Typescript >=2.4.0. It should be supported starting from v5.0.0 which is not available yet.

**Actions to change project's typescript version:**

1. It is necessary to set correct typescript version in package.json (2.5.3 in my case).
2. Run `nmp install` in project root (folder containing package.json), after that should work.
3. To be sure the right typescript version is used run `ng -v`