# Missing typescript options in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, ionic2, visual-studio-2017, windows-10

I have an Ionic 2 project which I need to build in VS 2017 in order to ship my application to Windows 10.

First problem I encountered is that I am using string enums in my code, which were giving me build errors.
I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191472/typescripts-string-enums-type-is-not-assignable-to-type) on stack overflow which stated that my Visual Studio might pick up different version of Typescript than the actual since string enums are only available in Typescript > 2.4

Then I tried to search for typescript settings in VS,
**but I can't find them anywhere**.
It seems that my Visual Studio is missing those settings which should be in *Tools > Options > Text Editor > Javascript/Typescript > Intellisense*.

**How can I find Typescript settings?** I don't want to refactor my usage of string enums.
I looked through already available answers but didn't manage to solve the problem.

Version of VS I use:
[image: Visual Studio I use]

Missing Typescript options should be here:
[image: Options]