# Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

Read [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45191472/3317808).

Instead of using constant variable declarations,

```
const directionUp: symbol = Symbol();
const directionDown: symbol = Symbol();
const directionLeft: symbol = Symbol();
const directionRight: symbol = Symbol();
```

using enum type in below code,

```
enum Direction {
    Up = Symbol(),
    Down = Symbol(),
    Left = Symbol(),
    Right = Symbol(),
}
```

---

How to resolve below error?

```
$ tsc --version
Version 2.8.3
$ tsc
tstut.ts(2,10): error TS2322: Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'Direction'.
tstut.ts(3,12): error TS2322: Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'Direction'.
tstut.ts(4,12): error TS2322: Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'Direction'.
tstut.ts(5,13): error TS2322: Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'Direction'.
```

Comment: Is Symbol allowed in an `enum`?

Comment: That's not valid. Just use `const`s

Answer (score 3):

A `Symbol` can't be used for an enumeration, only strings and numbers.

And it is not necessary, because the use of a `Symbol` is to be an unique indentifier, but a property in an enumarion already complies witht that request:

```
enum E1 {
   First = 1
}

enum E2 {
   First = 1
}

const p: E2 = E1.First; // error, even if the two values are theoretically compatible.
```

Comment: It looks necessary because, it does not require to make you think, whether to assign `1` or `"UP"` or `"RED"`. Value better be anonymous, but the value is required to be assigned. Sometimes, it is hard to choose values. In a `enum` type, const name is important but not value.

Comment: No, it is not required. You can define an enum as `enum E1 { First }`