# Why do I get the error Type '"x"' is not assignable to type "type Enum"

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have declared this in a file .ts,

```
export enum TipoAccesoDia {
    Menos300 = "menos de 300",
    Entre300y600 = "entre 300 y 600",
    Mas600 = "más de 600",   }
```

I don't understand why it gives the following error:

```
 Type '"menos de 300"' is not assignable to type 'TipoAccesoDia'.
 Type '"entre 300 y 600"' is not assignable to type 'TipoAccesoDia'.
 Type '"más de 600"' is not assignable to type 'TipoAccesoDia'.
```

¿Any idea?

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: the error simply gives when compiling, in the declaration

Comment: You need to paste the line where the error occurs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript's string enums - "Type ... is not assignable to type ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191472/typescripts-string-enums-type-is-not-assignable-to-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like `const type: TipoAccesoDia = 'menos de 300';`?

Because in that case, what you need to do is `const type: TipoAccesoDia = TipoAccesoDia.Menos300;`

That happens because `'menos de 300'` is type `string`, and not `TipoAccesoDia`.

---

If you still prefer to fo it like in the first example, you should use [magic strings](https://eddieabbondanz.io/post/typescript/magic-strings/) (`type TipoAccesoDia = "menos de 300" | "entre 300 y 600" | "más de 600"`), but I don't suggest it.